# Weird charaters in a stringified buffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, buffer

I have a particular context in which one data are transformed a lot to get transferred across network. At the end, when I try to get this data back, I have unwanted characters at the beginning of the string.

First, I get the data from a db and it returns it to me as bytes (`<Array.<byte>>`), fully readable with `.toString()`. The result is:

```
{\"company\":\"xxx\",\"email\":\"xxx\",\"firstName\":\"xxx\",\"lastName\":\"xxx\",\"providerId\":\"xxx\",\"role\":\"xxx\",\"status\":\"xxx\"}
```

These data are passed to another "environment" with a function (not developed by me and that I cannot change) that returns the data in a "I don't really know what format it is".

I can decode it with the following piece of code:

```
jsonIdentity = JSON.stringify(bufferIdentity);
Buffer.from(JSON.parse(jsonIdentity).payload.buffer.data).toString('utf-8')
```

However, at the beginning of the string, I have the following:

```
"\u0008\u0006\u001a�\u0001\u0008�\u0001\u001a{{\"company\":\"xxx\",\"email\":\"xxx\",\"firstName\":\"xxx\",\"lastName\":\"xxx\",\"providerId\":\"xxx\",\"role\":\"xxx\",\"status\":\"xxx\"}
```

Also represented like that in my logs:

```
��{{"company":"xxx","email":"xxx","firstName":"xxx","lastName":"xxx","providerId":"xxx","role":"xxx","status":"xxx"
```

How can I remove it/prevent it to get in my result? It prevents me from using the JSON.

Update: here is the buffer I get:

```
{"status":200,"message":"","payload":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,6,26,128,1,8,200,1,26,123,123,34,99,111,109,112,97,110,121,34,58,34,105,98,109,34,44,34,101,109,97,105,108,34,58,34,102,64,105,98,109,46,99,111,109,34,44,34,102,105,114,115,116,78,97,109,101,34,58,34,102,108,111,114,105,97,110,34,44,34,108,97,115,116,78,97,109,101,34,58,34,99,97,115,116,34,44,34,112,114,111,118,105,100,101,114,73,100,34,58,34,102,99,34,44,34,114,111,108,101,34,58,34,117,115,101,114,34,44,34,115,116,97,116,117,115,34,58,34,111,107,34,125,34,64,98,54,57,51,50,51,53,100,49,52,97,49,98,102,57,57,56,100,50,99,97,102,53,53,52,52,100,97,49,50,50,51,55,101,97,55,99,50,56,55,50,49,56,97,101,55,51,100,55,97,50,53,101,52,55,48,48,51,56,52,100,54,53,54,58,14,100,101,102,97,117,108,116,99,104,97,110,110,101,108]},"offset":10,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":133,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false}}
```

Comment: Did you open with a hex editor to see what are those characters?

Comment: @GeraldoMegale Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Is somebody doing some sort of weird UTF based attack on you or something? You can check the character codes [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm) and it goes "Backspace", "Acknowledge", "Replace", then the question mark, "Start of heading", "Backspace", the question mark again, "Start of heading", "Replace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. Solution is available on Jira here: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-14785?focusedCommentId=58680&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-58680

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out:

```
const yourString = JSON.parse(jsonIdentity).payload.buffer.data;
console.log(Buffer.from(yourString, 'base64').toString('utf-8'))
```

An ugly solution would be just trim or replace the characters from your result

Comment: I don't understand the first line of your code. No variable assigned to this value?